# Can we shorten spines on bezier curves?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

Is there a way to reduce the size of the spines poking out of bezier curves?

Or is there a way to generate smaller bezier curves with smaller spines?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines that you see are the curve's normals. They can be adjusted, or disabled in the properties panel under [*Curve Display*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/curve_display.html).

[image]